# On demand resources. Can't find export option

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to add on demand resources to an app that I'm currently working on but I don't manage to find the option where I can actually create the resources to upload them to a site. In theory, when opening the organizer I should see an export option but... I don't. Has this changed on Xcode 11?

Thanks

Comment: May be a dumb question but do you have them enabled? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/EnablingODR.html

Additionally, you may find some more information on the above site on how to export them

Comment: @nopassport1 yes, that's the first thing I've done :)

Comment: Anybody has any other tip?